# Is it possible to `eb deploy` at a scheduled time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

Sometimes I'd like the ability to run something like:

```
eb deploy --scheduled-for=02:00:00
```

when it's a low-risk deploy that I want to run out of business hours. I can see from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) that the above option isn't available. But I'm wanting to know the best equivalent for this kind of purpose.

I know Elastic Beanstalk supports blue-green deploys with a Load Balancer and multiple EC2 instances, although I currently only pay for one EC2 instance and would like to keep it that way for now.

All my customers are Australian, so deploying overnight would generally suffice for my purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a local Linux workstation (not specified in the question), you could use `at`:

```
 echo "eb deploy" | at -m 02:00
```

Some basic info about `at` is [here](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-cron-alternative-at-command-to-schedule-tasks/). One thing to consider about using `at` is getting it [outputs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82835/why-does-this-at-command-not-print-to-the-standard-output). Thus you could save its output in a file:

```
 echo "eb deploy > /tmp/deploy_output" | at -m 02:00
```

For executing commands on recurring schedule, you could use `cron`.

Comment: I like the solution. I'm on MacOS. I can't see the output from the command. I'm testing with `echo "echo 'hello' > temptemp" | at -m now` or even `echo "echo 'hello' > temptemp" | at -m now + 1 minute`. At first I needed to give iTerm2 "Full Disk Access" via System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access which stopped a permission check every time. But I still get no output in `temptemp` or `/tmp/deploy_output` whether I create the output file beforehand or not. I've verified I can see the job in `atq`. Any ideas? I'm not sure if it's even executing.

Comment: @stwr667 not sure about mac, but on linux have to start and enable `at` service. btw, just tested `echo "echo 'hello' > temptemp" | at -m now` and this works for me on Linux.

Comment: Ah ok, got it now. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478840 is a helpful answer here. TL;DR I had to also run `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist` to enable the `atrun` utility, and then give `/usr/libexec/atrun` Full Disk Access as well, like I described in the above comment.

Comment: @stwr667 Thanks for letting me know. Glad it worked out.